# Cookies bulk edition

Tags: cookies, bulk

is there a way in Firefox and Chrome to automatically bulk edit the content of cookies in order to keep only the information that lets you logged in and delete the rest ?

Answer (score 1):

No. The methods that sites use to keep you logged in vary from site to site, and then these methods also change based on site changes.

A better way would be to identify the sites you are actually logged in on, and then delete all of the other cookies. *NOTE: I don't know how this would be done automatically or programmatically.*

Another method that would accomplish most of this would be to disable third-party cookies, which most browsers have a simple setting to apply.